# how to override FOSUserBundle's schema file in other bundle

Tags: symfony, propel

I'm working in symfony 2.5 with propel for my project.

I need to add a behavior to `fos_user` table so I need a way to override the original schema file in my `src/` directory. Defining my project as a child of `FOSUserBundle` does work but this is not what I want.

Is there another way?

Comment: You need to a add a behaviour to the the table? Like the gedmo behaviours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can copy the original schema file to your app directory
and add the behavior you need. The way is exactly like overriding
any twig templates from vendors.
```

Comment: Yes that is another way but this can be done in app/ directory. what if someone wants to override the fos bundle schema in their bundle?