# Unknown behavior "typehintable" in Propel Symfony

Tags: orm, fosuserbundle, symfony, propel

I configured Propel ORM - Symfony ..
when I tried to run the command:
**bin / console propel: build**
**bin / console propel: model: build**
Symfony threw an exception

**[Propel\Generator\Exception\BehaviorNotFoundException]
  Unknown behavior "typehintable". You may try running `composer update` or passing the `--composer-dir` option.**

I use : Symfony3 + Propel ORM + FOSUSERBundle

Answer (score 1):

Although the `typehintable` behavior that is used in FOSUserBundle was removed with the latest version of Propel, they added the option to `typehint` columns in the schema ([see here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/pull/867)).

I haven't done this in a while so I can't give exact directions, but it would work something like this:

1. Override the FOSUserBundle schema.xml file ([StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376736/how-to-override-fosuserbundles-schema-file-in-other-bundle))
2. Add typehint columns in place of the typehintable behaviors in your new schema file
3. Migrate the new schema and build models